# I can't find Signing & Capabilies editor in Xcode

Tags: ios, build, cmake

I created an xcode dylib project using cmake & c++ linux project.
Then, I changed the code to make the build successful on iOS.

However, at the end of build, the following message is displayed.
I know how to fix this. However, the Tap (Signing & Capabilies) does not exist in my Project.

I will share my Build Setting. Please share a solution to this problem.

[General Tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CClEp.png)

[Build Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x90gv.png)

[Build Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rruph.png)

[Build Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDT1o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in compiling after adding 2 options below.

- XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM
- XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER